# My select area validation is forcing my page to automatically reload instead of running the validation

Tags: javascript

I have all of my other fields validating as I expect, but when I add in my JS to validate the select options, my page then just reloads once I hit submit. I have tried multiple ways to get the select options to validate, but I am failing to find a solution. I MUST use plain JS to validate the entire form, as per project requirements, and I am displaying an error message below each field in a span that doesn't contain any user input. I will post my JS below, and I can post my HTML if needed. I added in some extra spaces between my select area code to hopefully help with readability.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    alert("This page is best viewed with JavaScript enabled");
});

function validate() {

    // NEW: move this way up here so all validations can affect its value:
    var formValid = true;

    // function to check if a name has been entered
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;

    if (name == null || name.trim() == "") {
        document.getElementById('nameerror').innerHTML = "Please enter your full name";
        formValid = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('nameerror').innerHTML = "";
    }

    // function to check if an email has been entered
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;

    if (email == null || email.trim() == "") {
        document.getElementById('emailerror').innerHTML = "Please enter your email address";
        formValid = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('emailerror').innerHTML = "";
    }

    // function to check if a telephone number has been provided
    var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;

    if (phone == null || phone.trim() == "") {
        document.getElementById('phoneerror').innerHTML = "Please enter your telephone number";
        formValid = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('phoneerror').innerHTML = "";
    }

    //validate the select options
    var select = document.getElementById('select').value;
        if (select == '') {
            document.getElementById('selecterror').innerHTML = "Please make a selection";
            formValid = false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('selecterror').innerHTML = "";

        }
    


    //function to validate the textarea field
    var name = document.getElementById('textarea').value;

    if (name == null || name.trim() == "") {
        document.getElementById('textareaerror').innerHTML = "Please enter additional info";
        formValid = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('textareaerror').innerHTML = "";
    }
    // function to validate if any radio button has been selected
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('radio');
    var radiosValid = false;
    var i = 0;

    while (!radiosValid && i < radios.length) {
        if (radios[i].checked) radiosValid = true;
        i++;
    }

    if (!radiosValid) {
        document.getElementById('radioerror').innerHTML = "(Please check one)";
        formValid = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('radioerror').innerHTML = "";
    }

    // function to confirm if any checkbox has been checked
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('checkbox');
    var checkboxesValid = false;
    var j = 0;

    while (!checkboxesValid && j < checkboxes.length) {
        if (checkboxes[j].checked) checkboxesValid = true;
        j++;
    }

    if (!checkboxesValid) {
        document.getElementById('checkboxerror').innerHTML = "(Please select at least one)";
        formValid = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('checkboxerror').innerHTML = "";
    }

    // now that all validations have run, return the conclusion
    alert("The form has been submitted!");
    return formValid;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Contact Us</title>
    <style>

        .contact-header {
            font-family: cursive;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 50px;
            color: darkred;
        }

        form {
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
        }

        
        .contact {
            font-weight: normal;
        }
        .checkbox input {
            margin: 0 10px 0;
        }
       
        textarea {
            width: 20%;
            height: 5rem;
        }

        .sendRequest {
            text-align: center;
        }
        
    </style>
    <!--link to bootstrap css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--link for icons-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--link to external stylesheet-->
    <link href="restaurantStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <div class="jumbotron name-font">
                <h1 class="display-4">Dan's Cakes</h1>
                <hr class="my-4">
                <p class="lead">BIG NEWS!! Dan's Cakes will be opening a new restaurant VERY soon!!!!</p>

            </div>
        </header>
        <hr />
        <nav>
            <!--home icon link-->
            <a href="index.html" class="btn badge-pill"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a>
            <a href="menu.html" class="btn badge-pill">Menu</a>
            <a href="contact.html" class="btn badge-pill">Contact Us</a>
        </nav>
        <hr />
        <h2 class="contact-header">Contact Us</h2>
        <hr />

        <!--form for contact info-->
        <form name="contactForm" method="post" id="contactForm" novalidate onsubmit="return validate()">
            <div class="form-group col-form-label">
                <label for="name">Name: </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Please enter your full name.." required>
                <span id="nameerror" class="hint"></span>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email: </label>
                <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix"></i>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Please enter your email address.." aria-describedby="email" required>
                <span id="emailerror" class="hint"></span>
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phone">Phone: </label>
                <i class="fas fa-phone-square"></i>
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" required>
                <span id="phoneerror" class="hint"></span>


            </div>
            <!--select menu-->
            <label for="reason-select">Reason For Inquiry:</label>
            <select id="select " name="reason" class="custom-select" required>
                <option value="">--Please Choose an Option--</option>
                <option value="catering">Catering</option>
                <option value="private">Private Party</option>
                <option value="feedback">Feedback</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
            <span id="selecterror" class="hint"></span>

            <br />
            <br />
            <!--text area for additional info-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="info">Additional Information: </label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" rows="5"></textarea>
                <span id="textareaerror" class="hint"></span>
            </div>

            <!--radio buttons for visiting restaurant-->
            <label for="radio">Have you been to the restaurant?</label>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio" id="no-radio" value="no">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="no-radio">
                    No
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio" id="yes-radio" value="yes">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="yes-radio">
                    Yes
                </label>
                <span id="radioerror" class="hint"></span>
            </div>
            <br />
            <!--checkboxes for contacting-->
            <label for="checkboxes">Best days to contact you:</label>
            <div id="checkboxlist">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="monday" value="monday">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="monday">M</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="tuesday" value="tuesday">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="tuesday">T</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="wednesday" value="wednesday">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="wednesday">W</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="thursday" value="thursday">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="thursday">Th</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="friday" value="friday">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="friday">F</label>
            </div>
            <span id="checkboxerror" class="hint"></span>
            </div>

            <!--send request button-->
            <div class="sendRequest" id="contact-submit">
                <input type="submit" value="Send Request">
            </div>
        </form>
        <br />

        <br />
        <footer>
            <p>1123 Silk Way, Anchorage, AK, 99501</p>
            <p>907-998-0122</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script>
        document.contactForm.name.onfocus = function () {
            document.getElementById('namehint').innerHTML = "(Enter full name)";
        }

    </script>
    <!--scripts for jquery, popper, and bootstrap-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--javascript link to external sheet-->
    <script src="validate.js"></script>

    <!--<script>
        document.contactForm.name.onfocus = function () {
            document.getElementById('namehint').innerHTML = "(Enter full name)";
        }

    </script>
        -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem you have is you are doing:

```
var select = document.getElementById('select').value;
```

but the select is declared this way:

```
<select id="select " name="reason" class="custom-select" required>
```

it has `"select "` as ID, so you will get a `TypeError` saying you cannot read `value` from `undefined`. Its just a typo but what a typo! Just remove such trailing space:

```
<select id="select" name="reason" class="custom-select" required>
```

I think this should fix your problem. In addition, if you want to prevent the page from reloading, whether or not the form is valid, you have to **prevent the default behaviour** of a submit action. You can do that by calling `preventDefault` on the submit event, that you will need to pass to your function. Bear in mind that in this way the form will never be submitted, you will have to do it by yourself.

Pass the event to your function `validate` this way:

#### HTML

```
<form name="contactForm" method="post" id="contactForm" novalidate onsubmit="return validate(event)">
    ...
</form>
```

And prevent the default behaviour:

#### Javascript

```
function validate(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    ...  // The rest of your code
}
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) is the official documentation of `preventDefault`

Let me know if this helps you, otherwise, tell me what went wrong.

Comment: So the preventDefault() works to the point of not reloading the page, but the rest of my form validation never runs. Every field after the <select> no longer shows my error messages for blank fields. If I remove the <select> code, and run the page without it, everything works like it should.

Comment: @djsublett I think I found the problem, I edited my answer in correspondence. You were using the **wrong ID** for the select all the time.

Comment: THAT FIXED IT!!! A freaking space. AHHH... lol . Did you debug that to find that type error?? I am not great at debugging, so if you did, could you post what you did to solve that?

Comment: looooooool, I just saw it was wrong. Yeah, I am good at debugging. you are welcome!!

Please, @djsublett, mark my answer as **accepted** (green checkmark) and upvote it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I marked your answer, but it will not let me upvote it due to my reputation being less than 15.  s

Comment: One more thing. I want to add a success message to alert the user once the form has been validated and submitted. I have tried a few if statements but I am not having luck. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

When using a submit button the default of it is to refresh or direct you to your location specified in the `action` attribute when defining your form html tags. If your goal is to stop this refresh, you will need to place an `onClick` attribute to your button that holds a function to be performed (If you know any other ways to place event listeners on DOM elements you may take that route as well I am just using this as an example), you would then would pass a variable such as `event` to hold the event action into the parameter. Then within the function use `event.preventDefault();`, this stops the refresh. After that command you can do any other validations you need to do, then trigger a refresh or new window location, whichever is your goal.